# Variable wont get value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a variable that is not being assigned the right value even though it is saying that it is...?

```
Dim mID As Integer = CInt(Request.QueryString("mID"))

Using DBTable = MaterialStuff.GetMaterialHeader(mID)

                txtm.Text = CStr(CInt(Request.QueryString("mID")))
                txtmName.Text = CStr(DBTable.Rows(0).Item("mName"))
End Using
```

When I step through this and hover my mouse over `Request.QueryString` it shows that the correct value is being passed through however when I hover my mouse over mID it's blank, and stays blank even when I add a watch to it. Also, when I step through it when it goes to `MaterialStuff.GetMaterialHeader` the right values are returned using the `mID`...

I don't understand why it knows what the value is but it won't assign it to `mID` like I want... Any thoughts?

Comment: When you hover `Request.QueryString("mID")` which value do you see? Also you say `mID` is "blank", since int is a value type it can not be "blank", can be 0 though.

Comment: @Magnus When I hover over it it says `9`

Answer (score 0):

When you step through code, the current line you're looking at is about to be executed.

So - when you stop on

```
Dim mID As Integer = CInt(Request.QueryString("mID"))
```

mID has not yet been assigned a value because that's what that line does.

It sounds as though mID is being assigned correctly, because if I understand right, your code does then go on to execute successfully.

Try stepping through to the Using DBTable statement and *then* checking mID - see if it's got the value you expect at that point.

Also, this

```
txtm.Text = CStr(CInt(Request.QueryString("mID")))
```

Is overworked - it's exactly the same as:

```
txtm.Text = Request.QueryString("mID")
```

Comment: No because when the cursor is on the `Using` line I go back up to check what value `mID` is and it's just blank, but when it goes to the other function using the value it returns the correct data but it doesnt assign the data to the datatable so then when I try to access it to fill the textboxes its just null and errors out.

Comment: Wait a minute. You said above that mID is 9. 9 is not "blank". Which is it?

Comment: That's what I'm saying... When I hover over `Request.QueryString` it says it's `9` but when i hover my mouse over where I declare `mID` it is blank. It sees that the value is `9` which I want but it never assigns it to the variable